# Django - Object of type User is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset, drf-nested-routers

I am facing an issue with POSTing data (which has a User object) to a ModelViewSet.
Error: **"Object of type User is not JSON serializable"**

```
data_params = {
        "log_user_id": user,
        "device_name": "sampledevice",
        "log_user_email": "svc.netadc@ads.aexp.com",
        "feature_name": 'Subnet Automation',
    }

    print(data_params, "data_params")
    response = requests.post("<url>/netadc3/arista/ImplementationLogsAristaViewSet/implementationlogsarista/",
    auth=(<username>, <password>), headers={"content-type": "application/json"}, data=json.dumps(data_params), verify=False)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ImplementationLogsAristaSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    log_user_id = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ImplementationLogsArista
        fields = ('log_id','device_name', 'log_user_id','log_user_email','feature_name')
```

views.py:

```
class ImplementationLogsAristaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ImplementationLogsArista.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImplementationLogsAristaSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    pagination_class = None
```

models.py:

```
class ImplementationLogsArista(models.Model):

log_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
device_name = models.CharField(max_length=800, verbose_name='Device Name',default='sampledevice')
log_user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='User ID')
log_user_email = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='User Email',default='admin')
feature_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Feature Name',default='default_feature')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Implementation/Backout Logs'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Implementation/Backout Logs'


def __unicode__(self):

    return '%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.log_id,self.device_name,self.log_user_id,self.log_user_email,self.feature_name)
```

Not sure how to successfully POST the data with User into the ModelViewSet.

Comment: What kind of object is `User`? Does it have any bound methods? What types are its attributes?

Comment: can you show me the model

Comment: Updated post with models.py @TanveerAhmad

Comment: please remove log_id in serializer fields and then post data

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your `user` is Django User model instance, which is not JSON serializable:

```
data_params = {
        "log_user_id": user, # <-- here
```

```
data=json.dumps(data_params) # <-- here
```

You should put `user.pk` in `data_params`:

```
data_params = {
        "log_user_id": user.pk, # <-- here
```

Comment: Tried that, did not work. Data gets entered with blank log_user_id field.

Comment: Removing the read_only flag, I get error:

`{
    "log_user_id": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
        ]
    }
}`